# Airbrake Control Panel - Change Deployment Tags Colour

Tags: airbrake

We've recently set up a project on Airbrake. We post all errors, deploys to it and it's been working great.

The only nitpicky issue I have with it is that I can't find any way to change the deployment tag colour on the control panel. See the image below for an example:

[image]

Ideally I would like to change the "Dev" tag colour to red, "Live" to green and "Staging" to blue.

Is there any way to do this in the current control panel? The deployment POST request I am making is based on this: [Link](https://airbrake.io/docs/api/#create-deploy-v4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Airbrake team, here.

We don't support custom colours, they are picked automatically from the environment name. We try to avoid collisions but like in your case, they do happen. There are a total of 18 colours.

There are 3 very common choices that you may find useful:

- `production`: red
- `staging`: orange
- `development`: green

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we'll make do with the current colours for now. :)